# "Do" as main verb

Tags: grammar, verbs, questions

> 1. I do that work.
> 2. You do that work.
> 3. He does that work.

Here is my question: if we use the verb "do" as main verb how can we form interrogative sentences? Are these correct?

> 1. Do I do that work?
> 2. Do you do that work?
> 3. Does he do that work?

Please clarify my doubt.

Positive statement: *I do.*
Question statement: *Do I?* or *Do I do?*

In question statement which is the correct form?

Comment: You have it exactly right. In this case *do* acts as a lexical verb, not an auxiliary, so it requires *do-support*.

Comment: StoneyB's response should probably be posted as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have it right.

"Do that work" is separate and distinct from the other "do" in the sentence. They just happen to be the same verb in this example. It could just as easily be:

Do I go to the store?

Answer (score 1):

The auxiliary verb-full verb distinction is important.  However the distinction between *light verbs* and full verbs must also be observed.

Consider your question, i.e.,

> Positive statement: *I do.*   Question statement: *Do I?* or *Do I
>   do?*
>
> In question statement which is the correct form?

In order to answer this correctly it is critical to distinguish between light and full verbs.

[Light verbs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_verb#Contrasted_with_auxiliary_verbs_and_full_verbs) cannot be used in exactly the same way as full verbs.

The form **Do I do?* is incorrect because your verb, *do*, is not capable of bearing the meaning of the predicate by itself.

You must either use the first question—the tag question—or a fuller form of the second question.

The first form implies the full question by omitting it—forcing the reader to supply it entirely.

Either

> Do I?

or

> Do I do *that work*?

Again the change is required by the use of a light verb with a noun (**do work**).

You can avoid this by using a full verb.

For example:

> Do I walk?